# Error while booting Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Kernel Version 4.18.8

Tags: boot, kernel

```
[    0.077858] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.077858] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.077957] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.078621] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.078965] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.079046] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.088229] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.093582] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.093582] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8F06757AB800 0005CD (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20160422)

[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)

[    0.093582] ACPI: \_PR_.PR00: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.093582] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.093582] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8F06753BD000 0003FF (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.093582] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.093582] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8F06757FD900 0000BA (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.093582] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.093602] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.093606] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8F0675000800 000628 (v02 PmRef  HwpLvt   00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.093752] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.096004] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.096012] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.096407] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.096413] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8F0674C5A000 000D14 (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.097177] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.097198] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.097205] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.097226] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.097226] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8F0675330000 000317 (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.097226] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.097226] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.097226] ACPI Error: No pointer back to namespace node in package (____ptrval____) (20180531/dsargs-303)
[    0.097226] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Ubuntu, but I encounter the same problem after update kernel using Kernel Update Utility from v4.15 to v4.19.1 to get around the `failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware -22` issue (see post https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8sllc2/wlp58s0_failed_to_remove_key_1_ffffffffffff_from/).

It may be an issue that the ACPI code in the motherboard's BIOS/UEFI developed by MS is causing conflicts to new Linux kernels. See this post: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/acpi-error-what-means-4175605357/.

I haven't found any differences other than a booting screen with a bunch of messages. I will try a different kernel version and see if the problem goes away. Will update this answer later.